# Objective-C UICollectionView Scroll Up/Down

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview

Does anyone know, what method for UICollectionView, while scrolling Up/Down.
I need to change UICollectionView's Header while scrolling down.I am doing own calendar View.

I have following method that creates header view for section

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ASCalendarHeaderView *calHeader = [self.calCollectView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"CalendarHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    calHeader.MonthYearLabel.text = [calendar getCurrentMonthYear:calendar.today];
    [calHeader setNeedsDisplay];
    calHeader.MonthYearLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    if (indexPath.section){

        [calendar getNextMonth:calendar.today];
        NSLog(@"Some Text");

    }

    return calHeader;
}
```

But it increment month while I am scrolling up. Is there is method that mean while scrolling up and while scrolling down separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check this method for detecting the scrolling:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
```

It will be called every time you scroll, if you want to know if the scroll its up or down, register the offset of the previous scroll, if it's more, you are going up and viceversa:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger lastOffset;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{
   //Compare sender.contentOffset.y with lastOffset

lastOffset = sender.contentOffset

}
```

Comment: Sorry I thought about it, but how I can do Header change for CollectionView in this method?

Comment: Instead of creating a new header every time, just have a class variable with the header and return it in your method. Because it´s a class variable, you can access it every time you want and change whatever you want

Comment: could you please give some examples, direction?